# Is $\int_0^x f(t)dt $ bounded when $f$ is bounded and continious $?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals, proof-writing

Given $$f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$$ is continious,$f(t)\ge 0\forall t\in [0,1]$. Define $g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $$g(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$$. Now the question is whether $g$ is monotone or bounded etc.

NOw,to show that $g$ is monotone increasing $$g(x+h)-g(x)\\=\left(\int_0^{x+h}-\int_0^x\right) f(t)dt\\=\int_x^{x+h} f(t)dt\\=\int_0^h f(t)dt\\ \gt 0.$$ So this is monotone increasing. Done.

Now,I also think it is bounded. Because $f$ itself has a finite supremum.And after $1$ f attains no value so may be I should assume that $g$ attains $0$ after $1$.I mean if we take any $x=1+h,h\gt 0$, we get $$g(1+h)\\=\int_0^{1+h}f(t)dt\\=\int_0^1 f(t)dt+\int_1^{1+h}f(t)dt$$ Although $f$ attains no value in $(1,1+h)$ but the second summand $\int_1^{1+h}f(t)dt$ can be written as $\int_0^{h}f(t)dt$ which again is $\gt 0.$

Oh. So did I just got that it is unbounded? Or did I make any mistake?

Opinions please. Thank you.

Comment: You define $g$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but $f$ is only defined in $[0,1]$. What do you intend the integral to mean when $x > 1$?

Comment: Since $f(t)\ge 0 \implies g(x+h)-g(x)\ge 0$ ;Isn't it?

Comment: @mixedmath:umm should it be $0\ ?$

Comment: @learnmore: Yeah. ok $\le$ should replace $\lt$ right?

Comment: Make the domain of $f$ to be $\Bbb R$

Comment: @learnmore: can't. this was the question unless there was a printing mistake. Why? Won't this work with different definitions?

Comment: Then you can't define $g$

Comment: @learnmore: oh!I get it now. then if I define $f$ on whole $\mathbb R$ by $f(x)=0\forall x\notin [0,1]$ then it will be bounded and if $f$ is $\gt 0$ everywhere thaen unbounded,right?

Comment: Yes define like that;it makes sense

Comment: @learnmore: Or may be could I define $g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R.$ Will that do?

Comment: Yes you can also do that but then g is bounded because it is defined on the compact set $[0,1]$

Answer (score 1):

1. Your function $g$ is differentiable on [0.1] and $g'(x)=f(x)$.
2. With $M:= \max\{|f(t)|: t \in [0,1]\}$ we have

   $|g(x)|=|\int_0^x f(t)dt| \le \int_0^x |f(t)|dt \le \int_0^x M dt=Mx \le M$